# Unable to add phantomjs in my docker, getting error - npm ERR! `user` is not a valid npm option

Tags: node.js, docker, pdf, phantomjs

I am trying to add phantomjs in my docker file to generate html - pdf.
Below is my dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /
COPY package*.json ./

# Add support for https on wget
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache wget && apk --no-cache add openssl wget && apk add ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates

# Add phantomjs
RUN wget -qO- "https://github.com/dustinblackman/phantomized/releases/download/2.1.1a/dockerized-phantomjs.tar.gz" | tar xz -C / \
    && npm config set user 0 \
    && npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt
    
# Add fonts required by phantomjs to render html correctly
RUN apk add --update ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-freefont ttf-liberation && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN npm install --production
copy . /
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
cmd ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

But when I try to run it. it gives me below error.

```
npm ERR! `user` is not a valid npm option

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-19T11_55_55_953Z-debug-0.log
The command '/bin/sh -c wget -qO- "https://github.com/dustinblackman/phantomized/releases/download/2.1.1a/dockerized-phantomjs.tar.gz" | tar xz -C /   && npm config set user 0   && npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

This seemed to work fine a few days back. But all of sudden this stopped working and started giving me this error.

This seemed to work fine a few days back. But all of sudden this stopped working and started giving me this error.